# Firebase hosting setup but only for the domain name not the site's files

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting, domain-name

I read the [Connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?authuser=0)  documentation and have a question.

I have my own website with a domain name like https://greta.portplays.com/ and I want Firebase to recognize it so I can log my user into Firebase excellent Authentication system, and then use the Cloud Firestore document database.

**When I set my Firebase credentials like this:**

```
apiKey=AIzaSyA4LDo9EC12e2jqehf-fPqxfL3pkHvK8KPswo
authDomain=greta.portplays.com
databaseURL=https://greta-100-react-web-app-prod.firebaseio.com
projectId=greta-100-react-web-app-prod
storageBucket=greta-100-react-web-app-prod.appspot.com
messagingSenderId=50634773627812
appId=1:50677362734812:web:f5d4e234342b8d49a44fc05731
```

**And I follow instruction here in the picture:**

[image]

*The reason for why I do this is because when user login and the popup window show then user read that he is about to log into "greta-100-react-web-app-prod.firebaseio.com" and not greta.portplays.com.*

**So I set the Authorised redirect URIs so my domain are Authorised:**

[image]

My question is after waiting 13 hour for the DNS A record verification and as the image show "need setup",
what could I have missed to do since it still say need setup?

[image]

chrome 404 error since not Authorised redirect URI:¨
[image]

**Here's how I add the DNS A records**

[image]

**Serve me:**

[image]

**This is all I get when I open my domain now: can someone att Firebase look into this:** @FrankvanPuffelen

[image]

Comment: Did you setup Firebase Hosting?  This link shows the same content. https://greta-100-react-web-app-prod.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I dont have Firebase Hosting I have my own Host in Germany for my site and domain greta.portplays.com . I only did the [Firebase add custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?authuser=0). Yea I have done something [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029580/how-does-this-firebase-setting-up-custom-domain-work-in-my-case) here ever since I added the custom domain greta.portplays.com.

Comment: I think what I did wrong could be that I [accidentally](https://snipboard.io/OMDNr2.jpg) migrated the site. Must look up how to undo that