# How does this Firebase setting up custom domain work in my case

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, subdomain

I read this [Firebase Showing a custom domain during sign in](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain) and I don't understand in the doc where it say:

> 2. Go to the Identity Providers page in the Cloud Console, and select your SAML provider.

I can't see that I have SAML provider am I suppose to create one?

I have a new Firebase project just created a billing account today.

Under 4) it say:

> Update the Callback URL with your identity provider to use your custom
> domain instead of the default domain. For example, change
> https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler to
> https://auth.mycustomdomain.com/__/auth/handler.

But when I create the SAML provider there no way to change that Callback URL, only place where I see this to be changeable and I already have my domain as a authority handler, is in the Web client (auto created by Google Service):

[image]

Finally as this image show, should I add the 'auth'(I made a ring on the image) as a prefix for my domain only there or should I do that also when creating the domain as in this [doc Connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). I can't see anything about this in the doc do!

[image]

Comment: Running into the same problem. It doesn't look like there's a way to edit the callback URL.

Comment: @PranavPillai I ended up leaving it as it is, this was 6 month ago. I must investigate further when I get time

Comment: Same here, I have not found any documentation about custom auth domain for the Firebase admin SDK :/